# Segmentation fault on using the max Eloquent function

Tags: mysql, sqlite, laravel, eloquent

I am calling my Model within Artisan Tinker to get the max `stock_id`. Within Tinker, I keep getting seg faults.

```
>>> $blah = new App\StockTwits;
=> <App\StockTwits #000000007beee62900000001069541f8> {}
>>> $blah::where('symbol', 'AAPL')->max('stock_id');
Segmentation fault: 11
```

What's interesting is, if I use `->min` or `->count`, I get the results just fine.

Comment: Having a similar issue but occurs when mixing `select` with `with`. Be interested to find out why.